# MySQL Database, subject id

Tags: mysql

The image below is of a database I am learning to make from a tutorial. The author of the tutorial, as you can see from the arrow connecting the two tables, is trying to explain the relational nature of them. He added the `subject_id` to the pages table so that, whenever we're talking about a page, we know which subject it is a part of. Subject is the parent, page is the child.

My question is, is there something special about this syntax `subject_id` that allows that relationship to be made. For example, the name of the subjects table is plural `subjects`, so I don't see how subject_id makes a connection from `pages` to `subjects`.  Could subject_id have been named anything, and, if so, then how does the database know the relationship has been made?

[image: two databases connected by subject_id]

Comment: Where's this image you talk about?

Answer (score 2):

The names are totally irrelevant to MySQL; they are chosen to help humans understand what's going on. The way you tell MySQL about the relationship is to specify a [foreign key constraint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) as part of a CREATE TABLE or ALTER TABLE statement.

Answer (score 2):

It'a made by adding a foreign key to your pages table that refers to your subject table. Basically a foreign key tells the table that `subject_id` is actually a record in `subjects` and they are linked

Have a look at these links

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html